# Which brackest should be used where ? square brackets or curly braces while object destructuring ? I'm tyring to use context but bit confused

Tags: javascript, reactjs, destructuring, react-context

This is my context and I want to use it in my BookList component.

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react"
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid"

export const BookContext = createContext()

const BookContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([
    { title: "Deek Work", author: "Cal Newport", id: 0 },
    { title: "Principles", author: "Ray Dalio", id: 1 },
    { title: "Sapiens", author: "Yuval Noah Harari", id: 2 },
    { title: "Grit", author: "Angela Duckworth", id: 3 },
    { title: "Ikagai", author: "Hector Garcia", id: 4 },
  ])

  const addBook = (title, author) =>
    setBooks([...books, { title, author, id: uuidv4() }])

  const removeBook = (id) => setBooks(books.filter((book) => book.id !== id))

  return (
    <BookContext.Provider value={{ books, addBook, removeBook }}>
      {props.children}
    </BookContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default BookContextProvider
```

The BookList component:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react"
import { BookContext } from "../contexts/BookContext"

const BookList = () => {
  const { books } = useContext(BookContext)
}
```

Why the books variable is inside the  curly braces and not square braces ? even though the state i.e **books** is created with useState hook is an array.

Comment: It depends, are you destructuring an object or an array? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: `useState([` is being passed an array of objects.  Does that help? `const st = [{theobjects here]; useState(st);` would have the same effect

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss yes got it thanks

Comment: Because `useContext(BookContext)` returns the `{ books, addBook, removeBook }` object that you passed as the `value` to the provider.

Answer (score 1):

> Why the books variable is inside the curly braces and not square braces?

Because `useContext(BookContext)` returns the `{ books, addBook, removeBook }` object that you passed as the `value` to the provider. To destructure that object, you use curly brackets.

Sure, `books` itself is an array, but that doesn't matter - you're not destructuring it to get the array elements. To do that, you'd do something like

```
const [firstBook, secondBook, ...otherBooks] = books;
```

or even in one go:

```
const { books: [firstBook, secondBook, ...otherBooks] } = useContext(BookContext);
```

Answer (score -1):

- [] is used for destructuring arrays
- {} is used for destructuring objects

According to https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html

```
useContext(BookContext)
```

> "Accepts a context object (the value returned from React.createContext) and returns the current context value for that context."

Comment: One could also put an array in a React context.

Comment: That is correct, but the "BookContext" itself is an object, which means you have to use curly braces to destructure it and get access to the array.

Comment: No. Nobody is destructuring the `BookContext` object, that doesn't make sense. We're talking about the return value of `useContext(…)`.

Comment: Yeah that was my mistake, I meant the return value of useContext(), it is still context **Object**